# Azure ML ParallelRunStep ImportError: cannot import name 'SynapseCompute'

Tags: azure

Hi I got this error when I am running importing

from azureml.pipeline.steps import ParallelRunConfig, ParallelRunStep

The Error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a2ef999ba35b> in <module>
----> 1 from azureml.pipeline.steps import ParallelRunConfig, ParallelRunStep
      2 from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineData
      3 
      4 default_ds = ws.get_default_datastore()
      5 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/steps/__init__.py in <module>
     38 from .parallel_run_step import ParallelRunStep
     39 from .kusto_step import KustoStep
---> 40 from .synapse_spark_step import SynapseSparkStep
     41 
     42 __all__ = ["AdlaStep",

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/steps/synapse_spark_step.py in <module>
      5 """Contains functionality to create an Azure ML Synapse step that runs Python script."""
      6 from azureml._base_sdk_common._docstring_wrapper import experimental
----> 7 from azureml.pipeline.core._synapse_spark_step_base import _SynapseSparkStepBase
      8 
      9 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/pipeline/core/_synapse_spark_step_base.py in <module>
      5 """Contains functionality to create an Azure ML Synapse step that runs Python script."""
      6 
----> 7 from azureml.core.compute import SynapseCompute
      8 from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration
      9 from azureml.data.constants import DIRECT_MODE

ImportError: cannot import name 'SynapseCompute'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you update AzureML within a notebook? I run the following `!pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk` which originally failed due to dependency conflicts. After that I was getting the same error as you. Restarted the compute, upgraded azureml-sdk once more (although no package was installed) and after that the error was gone. Probably something was stack in memory in one of the running kernels while upgrading...